# How do I make a button fill in a td completely?

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

I have rows including a button in the last column:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](http://i.hizliresim.com/vg7qL4.png))</sub>

I want to make a button fill a `td` completely. I tried `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` together, but it didn't work. This is my code:

```
<td>
    <input type='button' style='width:100%; height:100%;' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(\"{$rec['memberID']}\")'/>
</td>
```

Why doesn't it work, and how can I make it work?

Comment: This is part of your HTML. Have you added any style? Then Code please

Comment: There is inline style.

Comment: did you use `display: inline-block`

Comment: Isn't there a default padding on a td?

Comment: I must agree with jlowcs. Cellpadding or some padding is applied to TD elements. So it's an XY question.

Comment: There is definitely a strange behavior with buttons in td containers: http://jsfiddle.net/y3zom5m4/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<td><input class='myclass' type='button' value='Delete'/></td>
```

CSS code:

```
 .myclass{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Try the fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/4r5roc2L/3/

Edited Answer here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4r5roc2L/4/

Comment: I need to give 100% to width and height, when I did, it didn't work.

Comment: well, if % is not working the, you can use px to manually set the width and height, however, I have updated my answer. Have a look and please let me know if that is what you wanted or not.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea.

Since the behavior of `height:100%` is clearly weird when a button is directly in a td, but not when it's a button inside a div or a div inside a td, let's combine those 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3zom5m4/2/

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <input type="button" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" value="Button in a div in a td"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works!

Comment: If you don't need to explicitly set the width of the `td`element, simply setting `height: 100%` on the `td` instead of adding a `div` works as well.

Answer (score -1):

A button whose width and heights are made 100% will fill the width of the `<td>` element but wouldn't fill the height of that element. The preferred solution to this issue is simply to make the height of the `<td>` 100% as well. e.g.

```
 <tr>
      <td><button class="btn" id="1">1</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn" id="2">2</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn" id="3">3</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn" id="plus">+</button></td>
      <td rowspan="2"><button class="btn btn-block" id="equals">=</button></td>
    </tr>
```

CSS:

```
td{
    height: 100%;
}
.btn {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That should work fine